# Submiting form more than once

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, submit

I have one page with 3 forms. Lets say they have the following id's:

- ajax_form_one
- ajax_form_two
- ajax_form_three

Each one has simple fields like text and select, but also a type='submit' button. Lets say they have the following id's:

- btSaveOne
- btSaveTwo
- btSaveThree

The code to execute the process of saving each form is like:

```
$("#btSaveOne").on("click", SaveOne);

function SaveOne(){
        jQuery('#ajax_form_one').submit(function(){
            var dados = $('#ajax_form_one').serialize();
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "saveOne",
                data: dados,
                dataType: "json"}).done(function(response)
                {
                    //do something
                });
            return false;
        });
    };
```

When I click the button the first time, the php function saveOne is called once, but when I click the button for the second time, the function is called twice. When I click it for the third time, it is called three times and so on, I mean... fourth time, four calls, fifth time, five calls.

If I leave and back to the page, this behavior start from the zero.

Why am I getting this behavior?

The core of my MVC I took from this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdtiltiRHWGXVHXX09fxXDi-DqInchFD)

The code is:

```
class App{

protected $controller = 'SaveController';
protected $method = 'index';
protected $params = array();

public function __construct()
{
    $url = null;
    if(isset($_GET['url']))
    {
        $url = explode('/',filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url'], '/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }

    if(file_exists('app/controllers/'. $url[0] . '.php'))
    {
        $this->controller = $url[0];
        unset($url[0]);
    }

    require_once 'app/controllers/'. $this->controller . '.php';

    $this->controller = new $this->controller;

    if(isset($url[1]))
    {
        if(method_exists($this->controller, $url[1]))
        {
            $this->method = $url[1];
            unset($url[1]);
        }
    }

    $this->params = $url ? array_values($url) : array();

    call_user_func_array(array($this->controller, $this->method), $this->params);
    return false;
}}
```

The Class Controller code is:

```
class Controller{

public function model($model)
{
    require_once 'app/models/' . $model . '.php';
    return new $model();    
}

public function view($view, $data = array())
{
    require_once 'app/views/' . $view . '.php';
}

public function dao($dao)
{
    require_once 'app/daos/' . $dao . '.php';
    return new $dao();
}}
```

The Class SaveController code is:

```
class SaveController extends Controller{

public function SaveOne()
{
    $fake_variable = $_POST['x'];

    $fakeObj = new FakeClass($fake_variable);

    $dao = $this->dao('FakeDAO');

    if($dao->save($obj)){
        echo json_encode(array('success' => true));
        return;
    }
    else{
        echo json_encode(array('success' => false));
        exit;
    }
}}
```

Comment: Have you disabled the default submit from the submit button. Reading the code above I thing you'll get the default submit behavior then you'll get the submit your executing in the onclick event. It doesnlt explain the cumulative nature of your problem but it will add to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because each time you click the button, Save one is getting called. What this function is actually doing is declaring a handler for when a form is submitted. So it's getting called the then redeclared so that two functions then three then four etc are attached to the submit event. 
Solution, either take this out

```
jQuery('#ajax_form_one').submit(function(){
```

or take the whole thing out of

```
function SaveOne(){
```

Comment: Perfectly!!!!! You saved my life :-) I took the JQuery thing out and let the function just with the ajax call, I mean, from var dados to return false.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have 4 opening { brackets and only 3 closing } brackets.

Not sure if that's the problem as you may have more code after this.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer

Comment: Thank you for your observation, it's a shame a newbie like me (with <50 Rep) cannot comment on questions :(